# Back up Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, repository, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having problems in backing up my newly created git repository. I have attached the file below. My questions are: What does Rake Aborted mean? Why does it say Project not created as well?

````
2020-03-11 16:16:50 +0530 -- Dumping database ... 
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... [DONE]
2020-03-11 16:16:51 +0530 -- done
2020-03-11 16:16:51 +0530 -- Dumping repositories ...
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "projects" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id"...
                               ^
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/repository.rb:17:in `dump'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Caused by:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "projects" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" ORDER BY "projects"."id"...
                               ^
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/repository.rb:17:in `dump'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:repo:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace** ```
````

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. it says table named **projects** is not created. may be try running ```"rake db:migrate"``` before running the rake task

Comment: I have not created any tables named projects. Should I create one ? How? I am new to GitLab. Please help                                                                               ```root@stl-ThinkCentre-A70-2:~/project1# rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
root@stl-ThinkCentre-A70-2:~/project1# ```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You pasted the output of a command, could you describe the origin of this output : what command was executed ? did you type it yourself on your local machine, or was it executed on some other machine ? you mention gitlab : did you get this error in a pipeline in your gitlab project ? etc ...

Comment: I started with this command in the local machine. ```gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create```  As for the error I get when I try to back up repository